# Add WMS Layer into map using Arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, wms, vb.net

I am going to add a wms layer to my existing map.I use this code:

```
public load_wms(ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.AxMapControl mapcontrol) { 

               // Create an WMSMapLayer Instance - this will be added to the map later

               IWMSGroupLayer wmsMapLayer = new WMSMapLayerClass();
               // create and configure wms connection name
               // this is used to store the connection properties

               IWMSConnectionName connName = new WMSConnectionNameClass();


                IPropertySet propSet = new PropertySetClass();
                propSet.SetProperty("URL", "http://173.244.165.194/geoserver/Land_Managment/wms?");
                connName.ConnectionProperties=propSet;


               // uses the name information to connect to the service
                  IDataLayer dataLayer = (IDataLayer)wmsMapLayer;
                  dataLayer.Connect((IName)connName);

               // get service description out of the layer
               // the service description contains inforamtion about the wms categories
               // and layers supported by the service

                IWMSServiceDescription serviceDesc = wmsMapLayer.WMSServiceDescription;
                IWMSLayerDescription groupDesc = serviceDesc.LayerDescription[0];


               // for each wms layer either add the stand-alone layer or
               // group layer to the WMSMapLayer which will be added to ArcMap
                for (int i = 0; i < groupDesc.LayerDescriptionCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    IWMSLayerDescription layerDesc = groupDesc.LayerDescription[i];

                  //  if (layerDesc.Title == WMSLayers.SelectedItem.ToString())//Checking if this is the selected layer
                   // {
                        // Configure the layer before adding it to the map
                        ILayer newLayer;
                        IWMSLayer newWMSLayer = wmsMapLayer.CreateWMSLayer(layerDesc);
                        newLayer = (ILayer)newWMSLayer;
                        wmsMapLayer.InsertLayer(newLayer, 0);
                        // add layer to Map

                        mapcontrol.AddLayer((ILayer)wmsMapLayer);
                        IActiveView activeview=(IActiveView)mapcontrol.ActiveView;
                        activeview.Refresh();



                  //  }

                }
```

But it does not draw anything
I can add it to openlayers but when I add it to ArcMap it does not drow anything..Can you help me fix it 
I am on arcobjects 10.2.2 and arcmap 10.2.1 also